# There are still screenshot uploads in progress. Apple App Submission

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Whenever I tried to Submit Review for my app, I got the following error message even I've uploaded all the required screenshots.

`Unable to Submit for Review`

`There are still screenshot uploads in progress.`

When I pressed view all files in Media Manager, I got gray blank picture screenshot which I've uploaded.

Blank Screenshot after uploaded
[image: Grey Blank Screenshot]

Here is the screen for error message.
[image: Error Message]

I've been stumbling on this issue for a whole day already.

Does anyone has faced the same issue? and How to get rid of it?

Thanks.

Comment: It is an issue on apple's side. You can only wait for them to fix it.

Comment: I have the same issue. There is a long discussion on app developer forum, but no general and reilable solution.https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/658887

Comment: Same issue here. It seems to be an Apple side problem, let's have a coffee and wait a for a while.

Comment: Still waiting for ours to process as well. We uploaded over 200 screens for all our languages... :(

Comment: Same issue here. I've been experiencing this issue since yesterday (01/19/2021) 7:30PM EST.

Comment: the correct answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73313352/app-store-screenshots-screenshot-uploads-in-progress-error-appscreenshotse

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Apple seems to have solved the problem.

The images that were in the upload process yesterday, this morning were already uploaded and I've been able to send my application for review.

EDIT:
It seems that the correct answer is in the following question:

[App Store Screenshots - "Screenshot uploads in progress" Error / appScreenshotSets Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73313352/app-store-screenshots-screenshot-uploads-in-progress-error-appscreenshotse)

Comment: I waited for 2 days, then everything was fixed by itself.

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same issue. The solution is to be patient.
This is what i did:
Upload screenshots one by one, after you upload each screenshot just refresh the page. And after upload if you see the screenshot is processing, remove it and upload again and refresh the page. Repeat the procedure till all your screenshots are up. Make sure you use Safari.

Comment: What worked for me was spamming 3 uploads of the same picture, one of them always successfully uploaded and I'd delete the other two.

Comment: @TheNoviceProgrammer Lol! that's very creative.

Comment: Haha, necessary knows no law! But I think the issue has been resolved for the most part!

Comment: The key for me was refreshing my browser ... that then showed the ones which had not successfully loaded.

Answer (score 4):

The most useful method is not to wait, but to constantly re-upload the waiting pictures

Answer (score 2):

I'm also facing the same issue, I just delete all my screenshot from every device and upload again and then getting the same issue, then after waiting a whole day, the next day I checked my images were uploaded.

It would appear that a Server side issue. While they fix it, we may need to trust that all photos will be prepared: on the off chance that you revive like clockwork, you will see that a few pictures that were gray with a cloud symbol are currently handled. I attempted and it would seem that it is a poorly conceived notion to attempt to supplant them once more. They all become dim once more. So how about we simply stand by until they are totally handled, while they work on the issue.

**Useful link:**
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/649241

**check my post:**
[Error: There are still screenshot uploads in progress. On Apple App Submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65809493/error-there-are-still-screenshot-uploads-in-progress-on-apple-app-submission/65817081#65817081)

Answer (score 1):

I compressed my images using *compressjpeg.com*. Now they uploaded fine.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue - tried to delete and upload again all screenshots several times, but nothing helped.

The reason was that we have several localizations but use screenshots only for primary language.
But **the broken screenshot was accidentally added to secondary language** and was not visible at the first glance))

Found understanding for that issue here

["There are still screenshot uploads in progress." when submit a new build](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/649241?answerId=612460022#612460022)

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an Apple server-side issue, here's a fix that worked for me:

1. Save current changes in your submission. If the "Save" button is greyed out, then this is ok.
2. Turn off the WiFi of your computer.
3. Clear the cache of your web browser.
4. Turn on your computer's WiFi.
5. Log-in again to Apple Store Connect.
6. Go to the specific app where you encountered the problem. This time, it shows one or few greyed out screenshots that causes the problem. You can just delete this screenshot by hovering over it and pressing the red delete button that appears. You can just re-upload such screenshots or just completely exclude it in the previews.

Comment: I opened dev tools & did an "empty cache & hard reload". One of the images was in fact grey. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same issue (at least **a similar symptom**): I uploaded screenshots for the 6.5 & 5.5 displays and other displays also, but when I click the "Submit for review" button, it gave me the same error as above.

In my case, the **solution** is:
> DO NOT use **JPG**, simply convert the screenshots to **PNG** and upload, then the issue is gone.  (E.G.: I was using Mac Preview app to convert/export the JPG files to PNG)

=====
By the way, the preview is not mandatory, I didn't upload the preview video but still, I can submit it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Our problem was uploading wrong size to Apple, e.g.: for 6.5 we uploaded the 5.5 images and vice-versa. Once we uploaded the proper images we need to wait for about 5 minutes and Apple allowed us to submit the app

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround FINALLY!**

1. Go to "Product Page Optimization" tab
2. Click in the plus sign to "Create Product Page Test"
3. Fields:
   3.1 Reference Name: Test
   3.2 Number of Treatments: 1
   3.3 Traffic Proportion: 50%
4. Click in "Create test"
5. Upload your images inside the "Treatment A" area
6. Click in "start test" and send it to review and await apple
7. Once this review was accepted, you gonna be able to apply the new images to your current published and/or published version.
8. Send you new app version to app review, like usual.

Answer (score 0):

It indeed doesn't get fix by itself, so don't wait.
Open **“View All Sizes in Media Manager”** in your submission and check every language for greyed out screenshots.
If there's just one screenshot that is greyed out, it won't let you submit.

Unfortunately it is a painful process if you have many screen sizes and localizations, but it is inevitable.

I don't imagine it myself, it is an official answer from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/649241

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still facing that issue just make sure your screenshots are png and not jpeg

Comment: Funny enought, converting my png screenshots into jpg (not jpeg) worked like a charm for me

Answer (score 0):

Experienced the same issue and i was checking for any images that were still uploading and had the cloud icon showing but it showed that all images uploaded.

I then clicked on "View All Sizes in Media Manager" and cycled through all the countries from within that page and it showed a picture that failed to upload in one of them.

After Re-uploading the failed image it finally got accepted for review!

Apple really needs to do something about uploading images/video, very frustrating experience.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to refresh the web and see if there were any image processing. Deleted that image and reuploaded it. Continued to refresh the web. If no image is processing then you can submit app for review

Answer (score 0):

I compressed all my my images  and then, I used Safari to upload them Now they uploaded fine. also, try to check on the image that you just uploaded every time you upload an image.
Before, I was using google chrome which was not uploading.

Answer (score 0):

For me, converting my `png` images into `jpg` (not `jpeg`) worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem that I had was that I couldn't install iOS 15, so I couldn't test my app in an iPhone 8 Plus, so I use a 5.4 image and resized it to 1242 x 2208 pixels (the ones that apple needs), they uploaded just fine, and they didn't show a red or gray image (error), they looked just like the other ones. So I had to create an image with the dimensions specified and create my screenshot there, this solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also have some problem. First remove all uploaded photos, change jpg to png. And it's uploading ok, but get this error again. I resolve it:

> 1. Go to your app version page where you see your screenshots.
> 2. Click “View All Sizes in Media Manager”. This should take you to a
>    page with all available display types and sizes.
> 3. Click the “>” icon by each display size to expand every section.

remove problems photos, upload again and it's working!

Answer (score 0):

Go the images section.

Check if any images is not visible and shows a grey placeholder rectangle with an upload (cloud) icon on it.

Delete that image and upload the same image again.

Do this for any such image you see.

Logout and Login and hit the Submit for review button. It should work!

Answer (score 0):

It can happen if some image contains alpha channels or transparencies.

During upload, it mainly shows that everything is fine, but it does not allow to save it.

1. Try to change the browser
2. Check images to avoid alpha channels