# Error: There are still screenshot uploads in progress. On Apple App Submission

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, store

First I uploaded images for **iPhone 5.5" Display** and **iPad Pro (2nd Gen) 12.9" Display** Screenshot images, which uploaded fine and press "Submit Review".

After getting error to upload screenshot for all type of iPhone, which mentioned. I try many time to upload screenshot for other two and press "Submit Review", I got this error. Even some images already uploaded.

> **Unable to Submit for Review.**
> The items below are required to start the review process: There are still screenshot uploads in progress.

[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM9eo.png)

[Link image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjJZ0.png)

I got gray blank picture screenshot which I've uploaded.

Blank Screenshot after uploaded

[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRHz8.png)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/649241

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a server-side issue. While they fix it, we might have to wait several hours for all pictures to be processed: if you refresh every few hours, you will see that some images that were gray with a cloud icon are now processed.

I tried and it looks like it is a bad idea to try to replace them again. They all become gray again.
So let's just wait until they are all processed, while they work on the issue.

Comment: Thanks for you comment, 
Yes, after waiting a whole day, the next day I checked my images were uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

In my own case, I had to log out clear the cache and cookies then log in back. It worked like magic! Appstore connect has so many bugs. At times you have to get into the inspector to read the actual error generated from the server